# Помогите убрать ошибку Unparenthesized `a ? b : c ? d : e

Tags: php, opencart3.x

в логах нашел такую строчку.
Помогите пожалуйста исправить.
Версия php 7,4
Opencart 3.0.3.7

```
Backend log: PHP Deprecated: Unparenthesized `a ? b : c ? d : e` is deprecated. 
Use either `(a ? b : c) ? d : e` or `a ? b : (c ? d : e)` in 

/catalog/model/extension/module/discount.php on line 932\n, referer: /oborudovanie/apparaty-tornador/

    foreach($discounts as $key => $discount) {
            $qty = end($discount);
            $largest_qty = empty($largest_qty) ? $qty['quantity'] :  ($qty['quantity'] > $largest_qty) ? $qty['quantity'] : $largest_qty ;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Ну там же ясно написано - нужно больше скобок. Вы должны явно указать, какой из вариантов вы хотите получить. Такой:

```
$largest_qty = empty($largest_qty) ? $qty['quantity'] :  (($qty['quantity'] > $largest_qty) ? $qty['quantity'] : $largest_qty);
```

Или такой:

```
$largest_qty = (empty($largest_qty) ? $qty['quantity'] :  ($qty['quantity'] > $largest_qty)) ? $qty['quantity'] : $largest_qty ;
```

Comment: Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in /catalog/model/extension/module/discount.php on line 932  поробовал и тот и тот вариант, теперь явная ошибка

Comment: @VitaliyProkopenko  `end` - "Возвращает значение последнего элемента или `false` для пустого массива.", возможно у вас именно случай пустого массива, нужно это отдельно как-то проверять, иначе `$qty['quantity']` будет давать ту ошибку, которую вы привели.

Comment: Перевел все на php 7.3 ошибки нет. спасибо